# Aurelia Bluebird error in Firefox

Tags: aurelia, bluebird

I just installed a plain-vanilla version of the [Aurelia Skeleton app for ESNext](https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation/tree/master/skeleton-esnext).

I fired up `gulp watch` and have the error below.  Any idea on what I can do about this?  Thanks.

The resource from “http://localhost:9000/jspm_packages/npm/bluebird@3.4.1/js/browser/bluebird.min.js” was blocked due to MIME type mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uninstalled node.js v6.10 and installed v7.7 then ran through the same exact steps:

- npm install
- jspm install -y
- gulp watch

And it worked perfectly.  I think it has to do with not installing dependencies, therefore the bluebird error.  But it has nothing to do with bluebird.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you forgot to run `jspm install` after `npm install`/`yarn`?

I was getting the same message with missing JSPM packages.